# force user to select combo option before processing to second form

Tags: c#, winforms

Inside my MainForm there is many buttons and one combo box.

Before processing action when user select any button I want to force him to first select option from combo box.

For example combobox is `cmbMyList` and button is `btnSave`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the button disabled if no option in the combobox is selected. Enable it when a selection is made. Use events to detect when this happens, for example by use of the [ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I usually add checks to my Button_OnClick event. Just to keep it simple:

```
public void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (cmbMyList.SelectedIndex.CompareTo(n) == 0) // n - your empty value index
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Selected value is not valid.");
     }
     else
     {
         // proceed
     }
}
```